# Jmeter regular expression extractor for capturing dynamic value within code

Tags: regex, jmeter

Here I am using Jmeter 2.6 to test a .net application.
While extracting dynamic value through regular expression Extractor, I am unable to proceed and getting the match count=0.

My expression is:

```
window.open('ConsumptionBatchSerial.aspx?Quantity='+ReturnQty+'&ItemCode='+ItemCode+'&Batch='+Batch+'&Serial='+Serial+'&StDetailsId='+StDetailsId+'','','width=810,height=350,left=100,top=150,resizable=1')
```

From this I want to extract `Itemcode,Quantity,Serial,Batch,StDetailsId`.

Can anybody have any idea on this concept?
Please post if you are aware of such scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to capture the parsed data, which is what would show up in the browser, something like this should work.

`(??)Quantity=([^&]*)&ItemCode=([^&]+)&Batch=([^&]+)&Serial=([^&]+)&StDetailsID=([^,]+)`

If that string is the exact string you want to match, then something like this should work.

`(??)Quantity='\+([^\+]*)\+&ItemCode='\+([^\+]*)\+&Batch='\+([^\+]*)\+&Serial='\+([^\+]*)\+&StDetailsID=\+([^\+]+)`

(can't yet comment anywhere to ask for clarification, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression Formats to get the following values

```
1. Quantity
2. Itemcode
3. Batch
4. Serial
5. StDetailsId
```

Regular Expression

```
Quantity=(.+)&ItemCode=(.+)&Batch=(.+)&Serial=(.+)&StDetailsId=(.+)','',
```